# Java File API in Windows 7 issue

Tags: java, windows, api, fileapi

Basically, I'm just trying to run a list of all the files in a folder using the list function from the Java File class:
`artistList = (new File(myPathName)).list();`

But what I get is some missing files, even after I have "show hidden files" in Windows 7. I'm wondering where these files are.

If it helps, the path I'm searching in is a folder like `/media` which I have organized into `/media/artist/album/title.mp3` for all my song data. The extra files I end up finding up are AlbumArt jpeg files (and I used songbird version 9 beforehand to sort the folders first, I'm just trying to rename the match the ID3 tags myself with a small Java program).

Comment: Are you using any of the "virtual file" and/or library stuff in Win 7? I know I've had problems in the past because where it _looks_ like the files are stored is not where they're _actually_ stored.

Comment: not sure what you mean exactly but I don't think these are stored in the libraries set. I put em in my own personal folder right outside the C drive.

Comment: Sorry, might have misread your question. Are you missing files from the `list()` call, or is the list call giving you extra files you can't see in explorer?

Comment: ah its ok its probably me that wrote the question wrong. When I do list(), rather than just all the folders I see when I open it,  list() includes a bunch of these AlbumArt jpg files that I don't see.

Comment: In addition to showing hidden files, have you tried unchecking the "Hide protected operating system files" option in explorer?

Answer (score 0):

With the organisation you descibed there will be no media files in the directory `/media` where your search / listing starts, you have to navigate trought subdirectories untill you reach `/media/artist/album` from there on you can get files that you actualy looking for. Also you might have to add a filter to `list` method and implement the filter's accept method to kick out thumbnails and hidden meta-files.

Here a piece of code (untested) that could help you

```
private final static Set<String> mediaExtensions; 

static {
    mediaExtensions = new HashSet<String>();
    mediaExtensions.add(".mp3");
    mediaExtensions.add(".wav");
    mediaExtensions.add(".ogg");
    // and so on
}

public static void list(File file, List<File> result) {
    if(file.isFile()) {
        result.add(file);
    } else if(file.isDirectory()) {
        File files[] = file.listFiles(new FileFilter() {
            @Override
            public boolean accept(File pathname) {
                boolean accept = false;
                int i = pathname.getName().lastIndexOf('.');
                if(i != -1) {
                    String ext = pathname.getName().substring(i);
                    accept = (! pathname.isHidden()) &&
                        mediaExtensions.contains(ext);  
                }
                return accept;
            }
        });
        if(files != null) {
            for(File f : files) {
                list(f, result);
            }
        }
    }
}
```